# After masturbation my clothing becomes wet

Tags: masturbation

After I masturbate, my bedclothes become wet, so I clean the wet spot with a cloth. I then wear another set of dry bedclothes.

Is that new set I wear also impure because I am impure? If I have those clothes while in an impure condition, do I have to wash that set or may I leave them as it is, and can I consider them pure and not have to wash them?

Answer (score 1):

> Is that new set I wear also impure, because I am impure?

No. When you are in junub you are not contagious because of it. Also the clothes you were wearing during masturbation are only impure if they contained pre-seminal fluid (Mazi), most of Ulama consider semen to be Taher (the Hanafite and Maliki are the exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

No the new clothes are not impure neither are the clothes you were wearing while masturbating. Even if you got a lil bit semen on your clothes they are still on impure. Also isn’t masturbation haram, Stop doing it.